# Setting a value in one dataframe by looking its value in another dataframe based on dates

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames in R.`Data1` has 2 columns `id`, `date` and `Data2` has 3 columns `id`, `date`, `level`.I want to set `level` column in `Data1` based on `level` and `date` columns in `Data2`.

```
Data1 = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1), dates = c("2014-06","2016-02","2016-05"))

id  date
1  2014-06 
1  2016-02 
1  2016-05 

Data2 = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1), dates = c("2015-07","2016-04","2016-07"), level=c(3,4,5))

id    date     level
1     2015-07   3
1     2016-04   4
1     2016-07   5
```

So resulting data frame should be:

```
id  date    level
1  2014-06   NULL
1  2016-02    3
1  2016-05    4
```

Comment: merge(Data1, Data2, all = TRUE)

Comment: not a problem of merge

Comment: `merge` does what you want no?

Comment: my communication skills are not that great...
As far as I understand its not a problem of simple merge...
Please see final dataset... 
values of level is based on the date range in Data2

Comment: date columns are not matching in Data1 and Data2... 
we have to see the range

Comment: But you don't define a range in Data2.

Comment: He wants to use the level that is greater/equal to the corresponding date but less than the corresponding date of the next level, I guess.

Comment: Like `2016-02` is greater/equal `2015-07` but less than `2016-04`, so he wants to use the level of `2015-07`. Is that right, @Arun?

Comment: yes... @LeoP. ( I am really sorry for not able to explain it properly :( )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the rolling joins from the `data.table`-package and converting the `dates`-columns to a date-class (see the note at the end of this post):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data1, key = c('id','dates'))
setDT(Data2, key = c('id','dates'))

Data1[Data2, lev := level, roll = -Inf, rollends = c(TRUE,FALSE)][]
```

which gives:

```
> Data1
   id      dates lev
1:  1 2014-06-01  NA
2:  1 2016-02-01   3
3:  1 2016-05-01   4
```

Explanation:

- Convert the dataframes to datatables with `setDT` and set the key to the columns which are needed for the join
- Join and create a new variable in `Data1` with `lev := level`. With `roll = -Inf` you roll backwards and with `rollends = c(TRUE,FALSE)` you only roll the first value backwards.

---

Setting the keys beforehand isn't necessary. You could also do:

```
setDT(Data1)
setDT(Data2)

Data1[Data2, on = c('id','dates'), lev := level, roll = -Inf, rollends = c(TRUE,FALSE)][]
```

---

Used data:

```
Data1 = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1), dates = c("2014-06","2016-02","2016-05"))
Data2 = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1), dates = c("2015-07","2016-04","2016-07"), level=c(3,4,5))
Data1$dates <- as.Date(paste0(Data1$dates,'-01'))
Data2$dates <- as.Date(paste0(Data2$dates,'-01'))
```

***NOTE:*** I converted the `dates`-columns to a date-format by adding the first day to each month. This necessary in order to properly do a rolling join as specified.

Comment: Thanks @Procrastinatus
I am getting little error for the following case...<br/>

Data1
ID  date
1   2013-12
1   2014-06
1   2015-09
1   2015-10
<br/>

Data2
id  date      level
1  2014-02   3
1  2015-10   6

Resulting dataset I am getting is :
ID  date        level
1   2013-12    NA
1   2014-06    3
1   2015-09    NA
1   2015-10    6

in final dataset, on 2015-09 level should be 3 not NA..

Comment: @Arun according to your response to [LeoP's last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259355/setting-a-value-in-one-dataframe-by-looking-its-value-in-another-dataframe-based#comment69720593_41259355), the `NA`-value is the correct one imo

Comment: @LeoP. It is certainly worth the somewhat steep learning curve. Once you know the basics, you will start rewarding the efficiency (also in typing) and the flexibility.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus

data1 = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1),date=c("2013-12-01","2014-06-01","2015-09-01","2015-10-01"))

data2 = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1),date=c("2014-02-01","2015-10-01"),level=c(3,6))

data1$date = as.Date(data1$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
data2$date = as.Date(data2$date,format="%Y-%m-%d")

setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)

data1[data2, on = c('id','date'), lev:=level, roll=-Inf, rollends=c(TRUE,FALSE)][]

in this example please see the output... 3rd row has lev column as NULL and not 3